# form_validation Codeigniter usando GET

Tags: php, codeigniter

é possível validar um input de um formulário usando o método GET? Quando defino que o método do formulário é POST o form_validation funciona mas quando defino que é GET a validação me retorna false. O código é basicamente esse:

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="<?=base_url('pesquisar');?>" role="form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="busca" required>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-plan">Pesquisar</button>
            </span>
     </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function pesquisar() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('busca', 'Termo de Busca', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo $this->input->get('busca');
    } else {
         echo 'não validou'; // Sempre entra aqui
    }
}
```

*Vi a seguinte solução, porém não achei muito certa:*

`$_POST['busca'] = $this->input->get('busca'); // só então executar a validação...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a documentação do [codeigniter3](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post) você pode validar outras arrays fora o `$_POST`

Antes de executar o qualquer `set_rule` você deve usar o `$this->form_validation->set_data` adicionando os valores que deseja.

Ficaria algo como:

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($_GET);
```

Ou "melhor":

```
$this->form_validation->set_data(array(
    'busca' => $this->input->get('busca')
));
```

Depois viria o `set_rule`, ficando algo como:

```
public function pesquisar()
{
    $busca = $this->input->get('busca');

    $this->form_validation->set_data(array( 'busca' => $busca ));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('busca', 'Termo de Busca', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        echo $busca;
    } else {
         echo 'não validou';
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu!